# How do I get the count based on the sequence as input

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name   | Session_key
------ | ------
Form1  | 1
Form2  | 1
Form3  | 1
Form4  | 1
Form5  | 1
Form1  | 2
Form3  | 2
Form1  | 3
Form2  | 3
Form3  | 3
Form1  | 5
Form5  | 5
```

I need to get the count of the form based on the form sequence input. Example in above case:  If I pass Form1 and Form2 and Form3 as input, 
the result should be as below.. input is not filter condition but just the sequence input

```
Name  count
Form1  4
Form2  2
Form3  2
```

if I pass Form1 and Form3 as input, the result should be as below:

```
Name  count
Form1  4
Form3  3
```

With above result set, how do i achieve count, based on the sequence passed.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Your description and desired data do not make sense.

Comment: I need to get the desired result based on the sequence in the way the name is passed.as an input

Comment: Updated the result set according to the desired needs.